# How to get an average from a row then make a list out of it

Tags: python

If I have a csv data that gives two row values of:

```
years grades
2001  98
2001  75
2008  100
2003  57
2008  50
```

I have more values but I will try to explain what I am trying to get here.

I want to get the average for each year. For instance, for 2001, the answer would be (98+75)/(# of counts 2001, which is 2 in this case).

```
 def construct_values(filing):
            """
        Parameters
    ----------


    Returns
    -------
    years: array of integers
    average_grades: array of floats
"""


  years, average_grades = [], []
    grades = []

        with open('grades.csv', 'r') as filing:
            next(filing)
            for row in file_path:
                year, grade = (s.strip() for s in row.split(','))
                years.append(year)
                grades.append(grade)


        return years, average_grades
```

What I did was just to get two arrays of years and grades. I don't know how to get average arrays and then print out like:

`2001, 88.5555` for instance if 88.555 is average.

Instead of being them as dictionaries, what I want to have are two arrays that will just return together.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a dictionary of grades with the key being each year:

```
from collections import defaultdict
grades = defaultdict(lambda: [])

with open('grades.csv', 'r') as f:
    year, grade = (s.strip() for s in row.split(','))
    grades[year].append(grade)
```

Then print the averages:

```
for y, g in grades:
    print('{}: {}', y, sum(g) / float(len(g)))
```

Comment: You lose order this way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `defaultdict` to form a dictionary whose value (`grade`) is a list , key is `year`,  then append grade to same year in the dictionary, after that `data` will be a `defaultdict(list)`:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'2003': ['57'], '2008': ['100', '50'], '2001': ['98', '75']})
```

Then, you can for loop the key and value to calculate the average:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
average_grade_by_year = dict()
with open('grades.csv', 'r') as filing:
    next(filing)
    for row in filing:
        year, grade = (s.strip() for s in row.split(','))
        data[year].append(grade)
    for k, v in data.items():
        average_grade_by_year[k] = float(sum(int(x) for x in v))/len(v)
print(average_grade_by_year)
```

`average_grade_by_year` will be: `{'2001': 86.5, '2003': 57.0, '2008': 75.0}`

Comment: Same comment as below. You lose order unless you use an ordered dict.